# Taking over a DotNetNuke website. Getting errors

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke

The project was saved as a website.  I am VPNing to the server and opening it from my machine.

When trying to build I am getting 60 errors (all are the same).

```
Class.Property.get must declare a body because it is not marked abstract or extern
Class.Property.set must declare a body because it is not marked abstract or extern
```

I spent hours yesterday going through so many SO questions that reported the same error and it kept leading to more and different errors.  So I figured perhaps maybe it was my lack of knowledge on DotNetNuke and reset everything back to scratch in hopes maybe someone will recognize where I could have went wrong.

This is one of the properties reporting the error (15 in total each with get;set)

```
public int CreditScore{ get; set; }
```

I open up VS click File - Open - Website and give it the path to the website on the VPN.  It opens in VS just fine.

My `Page Properties` for the project are: (If any other info is valuable from here just let me know)

.Net Framework 2.0

I've never worked with DotNetNuke before so I am hoping there is just some configuration issues I need to make and it will build just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code was written in a version of .NET that allowed:

```
public int SomeProperty { get; set; }
```

(.NET 3.5 or 4.0?)

And you are compiling it with the version that does not do auto-backing of properties with fields.

Comment: Is there an easy way to tell which version I should change this to?

Comment: Auto properties were introduced in  C# 3.0 according to [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx).

Comment: It's *not* about the version of .NET, it's about the version of the C# compiler. You just need to use a newer version of Visual Studio (and therefore a newer compiler). Your project can continue to target the same version of .NET as it currently does.

Comment: How do I change the compiler?  I have VS 2012 I doubt it's from using an old version of VS.

Comment: Project - Properties - Application - Target Framework